# Building a runner/executor/interpreter for a simple Java/Groovy DSL

Tags: java, compiler-construction, antlr, interpreter, dsl

I am building designing a super-simple, task-oriented, scripting language that might even be a prime candidate for a DSL. The idea is that non-programmers would be able to slap together "scripts" written in this "language" without really needing to know anything about (good) programming. Something *super*, *super* simple like:

```
Dog dog = new Dog   
dog goto waterBowl
dog drinks water
dog takes nap
```

That's a *rough* idea of the type of "statements" the scripts would contain (don't read into them too much).

So I need something to interpret these statements at runtime and actually do something when they are executed (sequentially, one statement at a time).

Can [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) be used for this type of runtime interpretation? My *understanding* is that its *just* a compiler generator. I don't really need a compiler; I just need something that can execute that statements of my super-simple language/DSL. Ideas as to what tools/libs might be prime candidates for me?

Comment: Would you be open to building your DSL inside [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Writing+Domain-Specific+Languages) or [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/1403). Your example seems like something that could be done in Scala quite easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can ANTLR be used for this type of runtime interpretation?

No, ANTLR cannot be used for the interpretation/evaluation. ANTLR is a parser generator: given the grammar for a language, it generates a parser for it. This parse can then be used to traverse over the parse tree and you yourself can evaluate it using plain code.

> My understanding is that its just a compiler generator.

If by "compiler" you mean a translator, then, yeah, you could call it that, although I find "parser generator" a better term.

> I don't really need a compiler; I just need something that can execute that statements of my super-simple language/DSL. Ideas as to what tools/libs might be prime candidates for me?

[Any parser generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators) can help you create a parser for your language, but what should happen after parsing is something you'll need to program yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Bart Kiers (+1) - so it sounds like ANTLR can produce a parser that could then be used to interpret the statements of my script lang to actual code, **yes??** If so, then let's say I have a Java class called `DogDrinkWaterStrategy`, and I want its `drinkWater(Dog)` method to be executed when the 3rd line of my script (`dog drinks water`) executes. How do I "tie" my ANTLR-generated parser to the `DogDrinksWaterStrategy` class? In other words, how do I get the generated parser to actually *do* something when it executes a statement? Thanks again!

Comment: If your language is real simple, you could just [evaluate it on the fly](https://docs.google.com/document/edit?hgd=1&id=1VnHEt38GSyNFmCmE5WjvE1UB2E1vgvs5l-5EB7lhoow) (called *Syntax Driven Programming* in the doc). Let's not misuse these small comment boxes for extansive Q&A's though: give it a try, and create a new question when you get stuck. Good luck!